# Using Camera in Today View Widget

Tags: xcode, swift, camera, ios8, avcapturesession

This may sound odd - and I know it seems unlikely to work - but is there any reason to think that an AVCaptureSession would not work as a notification centre (today view) widget? The code to display the camera definitely works, I have tried it in a regular view controller, but, with a green background, only the green background shows in today view, not the camera feed.

So my question is: is it possible to access the camera from today view widgets/extensions?

Answer (score 1):

No the camera is not accessible, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensibilityPG.pdf

see page number 14